# How to forward Thunderbird emails to another email address

Tags: thunderbird

How to forward all emails that come into Thunderbird to another email address automatically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1157749 for an explanation of forwarding.

Thunderbird must be up and running to find emails and forward them, and it is done with Thunderbird's 'Rules'.

Create a Message Filter which matches all messages, and then select forwarding.

Alternate solution:
If your ISP offers 'dot-forward' files, you can have the ISP do the forwarding without having to have Thunderbird up and running.